# How to SUM corresponding values from duplicate rows

Tags: vba, excel

I need to know how to write an Excel macro to SUM values from duplicate rows:

input:

```
red     2
red     3
.
.
blue    4
blue    5
blue    6
```

My NEEDED output:

```
red     2     5
red     3
.
.
blue    4     15
blue    5
blue    6
```

I need a new column showing the SUMs (5, 15...in this example) on the same first rows of the duplicate group of records.

I have tried this code (from Internet):

```
Sub count()
'
' count Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+a
'

    Dim ColumnsCount As Integer

    ColumnsCount = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.count

    ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Activate


    Do While ActiveCell.Row  &lt=   ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.count
        If ActiveCell.Value = ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Value Then
            For i = 1 To ColumnsCount - 1
                ActiveCell.Offset(0, i).Value = ActiveCell.Offset(0, i).Value + ActiveCell.Offset(1, i).Value
            Next
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Delete shift:=xlShiftUp
        Else
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
        End If
    Loop


    Range("C9").Select
End Sub
```

But the output came out as:

```
red     5
blue    15
```

I don't want to combine/merge duplicate records.
Thx much.

Comment: are the 'colors' always sorted? you can use [COUNTIF()](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/countif-HP005209029.aspx)

Comment: comment out the line with the `delete` and see if youre happy enough with the results

Comment: "colors" col. is already sorted. I have tried many combinations of COUNTIF()'s without any success. Do you happen to know the right formula combination? Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
=IF(B3<>B4,SUMIF($B$4:$C$13,$B4,$C$4:$C$13),"")
```

The `IF()` statement checks two vertically-adjacent cells in the `B` column to see if they are the same.  This determines whether the result will be visible.  So if the current row has `blue` and the row above has `red`, then the value will show.  Otherwise it won't.

`SUMIF()` rings up the total for all cells that have a value in the `B` column that matches this row's value for the `B` column.

Obviously named ranges would be an improvement...

```
=IF(B3<>B4,SUMIF(LabelsAndValues,$B4,ValuesOnly),"")
```

Comment: best of all, no VBA needed.

Comment: More info: the number of duplicate records are not fixed.

Comment: More info: I only need to compare col A (text) for duplicate records, if they are then I want to add the corresponding values (number) in col B and display the sum in col C (at the start of the duplicate group) Thx.

Comment: The number of duplicate records should not matter, EXCEPT it may create a #REF issue when comparing two vertically-adjacent cells.  That can be solved by adding a bit to the formula given.

Comment: "I only need to compare col A (text) for duplicate records, if they are..."  -- I've reviewed this a few times, and I can't see any problem with the answer I gave.  Either I'm not understanding your need, or you don't understand my solution.  Hope we can get it figured out.

Comment: I copied and pasted your formula in col c (C1, C2, C3...) they all showed: 0

Comment: That's a start.  Reduce the formula down to the `SUMIF()` clause and trouble-shoot till you get a result other than 0.  Hmmm, you said you were having trouble getting `COUNTIF()` to work.  Well, let us know.

Comment: I think I use a wrong terminology: It should say Search for duplicate CELLs (not records) in col A (text) , if they are then add/sum all corresponding values (numbers) (in same rows) in col B and display the totals in col C (in the start of rows of the duplicate cells). Thx

Comment: `=IF(A3<>A4,SUMIF($A$4:$B$13,$A4,$B$4:$B$13),"")` -- this would go in cell `C4`.  This assumes you are interested in rows 4 to 13; adjust as needed.

Comment: Thx much...It works! Also could this formula be modified to work if col A cells are not pre-sorted? if so, please help!?

Comment: That does complicate things.  Maybe it deserves its own post.  :-)